# Split and save the data selectively from one table to another mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, union

Split the data selectively

I have a table with following fields

Table-1

```
Publication_ID, Student_ID, Q1,A1,Q2,A2,Q3,A3,Q4,A4......................Q249,A249,Q250,A250
```

Sample data

```
100, 123, 1, B, 2, A, 3, C,4, B, 5, D, 6, B,..........................120, C
100, 124, 1, C, 2, C, 3, D,4, C, 5, D, 6, B,.....................109, B
100, 125, 1, B, 2, C, 3, C,4, B, 5, D, 6, A,..........................120, C
100, 126, 1, C, 2, B, 3, A,4, B, 5, C, 6, D,..............................................250, D
```

Now I would like to save the data od above table to Another table in this format

Table-2

```
Publication_ID, Student_ID, Q,A
100, 123, 1,B
100, 123, 2,A
100, 123, 3,C
100, 123, 4,B
100, 123, 5,D
100, 123, 6,B
100, 124, 2,A
100, 124, 3,C
100, 124, 4,B
100, 124, 5,D
100, 124, 6,B
100, 125, 1,B
100, 125, 2,A
100, 125, 3,C
100, 125, 4,B
100, 125, 5,D
100, 125, 6,B
```

---

---

Please note that the number of field filled in the table 1 may not be same for all the rows of data. So it should not insert empty fields to the Table-2  from Table-1

Please help me in this regard

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So basically you're normalizing the tables (yay!). But there' not automatic method to do this in mysql. You will have to run a `insert into ... select from` query for EVERY column in the old/bad table.

Comment: This will be executed after an import event in the Table1. The problem is the number of question and answers may not be 250 always. There are some exams with 100 questions. I wrote query with union so it will save all 250 field data. But it saves data of empty field in which no. of questions are less than 250. Pls see the query

Comment: $result =  ("INSERT IGNORE INTO Table-2  (`publication_ID`, `Student_ID`, `Question#`, `Answer`) 
SELECT publication_ID, Student_ID, '1', `1` FROM Table-1 UNION    
SELECT publication_ID, Student_ID, '2', `2` FROM Table-1 UNION    
SELECT publication_ID, Student_ID, '3', `3` FROM Table-1 UNION ...............................................................................

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table-2(SELECT Publication_ID,Student_ID,Q1,Q2,....A1,A2... FROM table-1)
```

If i understood that correctly

Comment: Q1 stands for Question1 and A1 Stands for Answer1 and so on. The table structure is as I have mentioned above.

Comment: I would like to get Publication_ID, Student_ID and Q1,A1 in one record. like wise Publication_ID, Student_ID and Q2,A2, and Publication_ID, Student_ID and Q3,A3 so on.  For any record if the Q* is null it should stop executing further for the same record and should move to next record on the Table-1

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to normalize some kind of table. So it shouldn't be an issue to perform multiple data manipulation statements in order to achieve the desired result. Something like that might do the trick:

```
SET autocommit = 0

-- repeat for n for 1 to 249
INSERT INTO T2
  SELECT Publication_ID, Student_ID, Qn, An WHERE Qn IS NOT NULL

COMMIT
```

If you really need to execute the migration without using a host language, you could use a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate()
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM T2;
  SET @n = 1;
  REPEAT
    SET @p = CONCAT('INSERT INTO T2 SELECT Publication_ID, Student_ID, Q', @n, ' as Q A', @n, ' WHERE Q IS NOT NULL');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @p;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SET @n = @n+1;
  UNTIL @n > 249
  END REPEAT;
END //

CALL migrate()
```